# JavaScript Countdown to Redirect another page when it hits 00:00

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JavaScript Countdown timer set for 30 min. I'm trying to redirect the existing page to redirect to the exit.php page when the timer hits 00:00

My code goes as:

```js
function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function() {
  var fiveMinutes = 60 * 30,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer">
  <div>Section</div>
  <div class="time">
    <strong>Time left: <span id="time">30:00</span></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Help Is Appreciated..

Comment: why you want to use complex algorithm .--> this is   a simple way <script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='form2.html'},5000);</script>

Comment: @pedramshabani because he wants the timer number to change as well

Answer (score 5):

Here's my go at this, hope this is what you wanted:

https://jsfiddle.net/jom9s562/

```js
var time = 30 * 60;
setInterval(function() {
  var seconds = time % 60;
  var minutes = (time - seconds) / 60;
  if (seconds.toString().length == 1) {
    seconds = "0" + seconds;
  }
  if (minutes.toString().length == 1) {
    minutes = "0" + minutes;
  }
  document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;
  time--;
  if (time == 0) {
    window.location.href = "exit.php";
  }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div class="timer" onload="timer(1800)">
  <div>Section</div>
  <div class="time">
    <strong>Time left: <span id="time">Loading...</span></strong>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hei, your code is good, but i cant change my existing code. however, if you can add few lines to my "existing code" and get me what i have asked that would be awesome

Comment: @ScienceGeek Why can't you change the existing code